# How do you modify an IOS swift 3 app to use Inter-App Audio (IAA)

Tags: ios, audio

I am writing a swift 3 audio app that uses AVFoundation, AVPlayer and AVAudioSession.  I've accessed the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/InterAppAudioSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) for Inter-App Audio (IAA) but all the coding is in objective-C.  I'd like something similar for Swift 3 as some aspects seem too difficult to convert to swift3.   Perhaps somebody has already achieved this in swift3.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a solution ?

Comment: Afraid not.   I'm hoping to look at this again over the next 8 weeks, totally rewriting from scratch the audio component of the App.  I was hoping Apple might have updated their documentation by then, but it looks like they haven't.   Perhaps Apple doesn't really support IAA for the swift3 / 4 codebase.